# jquery in html tag: on mouseover="myfunction();"

Tags: php, jquery, html, mouseenter

Is it possible to have a jquery mouseover in a html tag?

```
for(x=1; isset($_COOKIE["link$x"]); $x++)
    echo <div id="'.$x.'" onLoad="myfunction('.$x.')">
}
```

Like this example above but with "mouseenter" insted of "onLoad" ?

```
for(x=1; isset($_COOKIE["link$x"]); $x++)
    echo <div id="'.$x.'" OnMouseEnter="myfunction('.$x.')">
}
```

and then in javascript

```
function myfunction(which){
    document.getElementById(which).style.backgroundColor = red;
}
```

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/extended-event-attributes/onmouseenter - have you tried using mouseenter? EDIT: Here you go -> http://jsfiddle.net/Le3kk/

Comment: you can use `onmouseover` event for this as there is no `onMouseEnter` event in HTML as attribute.

Comment: On my page nothing happens, maybe because i echo out the div with php? Is there any way to do mouseEnter with javascript and jquery?

Comment: @Gasim your example works in jsfiddle but not om my page..? i have copied the exact code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in your comment, that you have multiple divs that should be fired on mouseenter, in this case you have to use "class" instead of "id"

```
<div class="myDiv">container1</div>
<div class="myDiv">container2</div>
<div class="myDiv">container3</div>
```

and in your jQuery code:

```
$( ".myDiv" ).mouseenter(function() {
$( this ).text( "mouse enter" );
})

$( ".myDiv" ).mouseleave(function() {
$( this ).text( "mouse leave" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Tag

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

and in your jQuery code:

```
$( "#myDiv" ).mouseenter(function() {
$( this ).text( "mouse enter" );
})

$( "#myDiv" ).mouseleave(function() {
$( this ).text( "mouse leave" );
});
```

Comment: thanks! but if i have many divs with id myDiv1, myDiv2, myDiv3, and when i enter myDiv2 i only want some thing in myDiv2?

Comment: but i dont know how many divs i will end up with, I add one each time i press a button

Comment: Give them the same class name, this will work, please find the answer below

Comment: use that structure accrodingly, but use class="myDivSets" and it'll apply to any div that you wanted to be manipulated (in other words...use same approach but use class="" instead of id="" from my first comment..